# Simple proof of existence of number field extension with the same roots of unity?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, alternative-proof, roots-of-unity

I'm looking for a brief proof of the following statement:

> Let $K$ be a number field and $p$ a prime number. Then there exists a field extension $L\supset K$ of degree $p$ with $\mu(L)=\mu(K)$.

My current approach is to first show that there exist infinitely many degree $p$ field extensions of $K$ that are pairwise nonisomorphic (over $K$), and then that there are only finitely many degree $p$ field extensions $L\supset K$ with $\mu(L)\neq\mu(K)$, up to isomorphism. For this I invoke quite a few small results from algebraic number theory, and the result is that there are *infinitely many* such field extensions, though I only need one. So my question is;

> Is there a simple, uninvolved proof of the statement above?

Comment: If $[L:K]=p$ and $\zeta$ is a root of unity in $L\setminus K$, then $L=K[\zeta]$ and $L/K$ is Galois as it contains all conjugates of $\zeta$. 
Let $n$ be minimal with $\zeta^n\in K$. As every $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^k$ with $\gcd(k,n)=1$ leads to an automorphism, we conclude $\phi(n)=p$. This is only possible if $p=2$ and $n\in\{3,4,6\}$.
As $K$ contains only finitely many roots of unity, there are ultimately only finitely many roots of unity that we have to "avoid". I guess this means that $L=K[\sqrt[p]q]$ with $q\gg0$ should work.

Answer (score 5):

Choose a prime number $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4p$ not dividing the discriminant of $K$, and let $F$ be the subfield of degree $p$ inside the field of $q$-th roots of unity. Observe that $F$ is real. The extension $KF/K$ is ramified exactly at $q$. The field $L = KF$ does not contain the $q$-th roots of unity since $L \cap {\mathbb Q}(\zeta_q) = F$. If $L$ contains some $n$-th root of unity with $n$ coprime to $q$, then $L$ must contain $K(\zeta_n)$, which is unramified at $q$. But $L/K$ is completely ramified at the primes above $q$: contradiction.

Comment: So $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is the intermediate extension containing the ramification of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_q)/\mathbb{Q}$ at $q$, and you are transferring this ramification to $KF/K$

Comment: You're right, but if $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4p$, then $q \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, and we may choose $F$ real. I should have said that. For the second question: yes.